# Count multiple field occurrences based on distinct field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to be able to group and count multiple fields in one query. I have tried with aggregations but cannot make it work so any help would be appreciated.
I have a collection with documents like this

```
[{
  _id:ObjectId("abc"),
  "who":"person1",
  "action":"joined"
},{
  _id:ObjectId("def"),
  "who":"person2",
  "action":"joined"
},{
  _id:ObjectId("ghi"),
  "who":"person1",
  "action":"left"
}]
```

and I would like the output to be

```
[{
  "who":person1",
  "total":2,
  "left":1,
  "joined":1
},{
  "who":person2",
  "total":1,
  "left":0,
  "joined":1
}]
```

Where total is the count of the action field and then the two options for the action field are counted dependent on the 'who' field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) along with [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html) and apply [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) to determine whether `action` is `left` or `joined`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$who",
            total: { $sum: 1 },
            left: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$action", "left" ] }, 1, 0 ] } },
            joined: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$action", "joined" ] }, 1, 0 ] } }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z9HCbh_UVFJ)